# Flutter Firebase update will not stop updating node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, int, operators, flutter

I'm searching for an int value in my firebase node and decreasing it.  It successfully decreases and prints the correct info to my log once.  When I attempt to update the node with the new int it repeats as if it where in a loop.  How can I get it to update a single time?  Here is my code...

```
if (vidRank == 1) {
      await fb.child('UserVideo/${userid}/Vid1').onValue.listen((Event event){
        if (event.snapshot != null){
          var vid1id = event.snapshot.value['videoID'].toString();
          fb.child('NumberOnes/${vid1id}').onValue.listen((Event onesEvent){
            if (onesEvent.snapshot != null){
              var onesValue = (onesEvent.snapshot.value['Value'] as int);
              final vidValue = onesValue - 1;
              print("Inside  ${vidValue}");
              fb.child('NumberOnes/${vid1id}').update({
                'Value': vidValue
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a single action, use `.once()`

```
if (vidRank == 1) {
  var event = await fb.child('UserVideo/${userid}/Vid1').once();
  if (event.snapshot != null){
    var vid1id = event.snapshot.value['videoID'].toString();
    var onesEvent = await fb.child('NumberOnes/${vid1id}').once();
    if (onesEvent.snapshot != null){
      var onesValue = (onesEvent.snapshot.value['Value'] as int);
      final vidValue = onesValue - 1;
      print("Inside  ${vidValue}");
      fb.child('NumberOnes/${vid1id}').update({
        'Value': vidValue
      });
    }
  }
}
```

otherwise an update will cause another event for `listen(...)` and you have a perfect loop.